# Does a failing testcase in SoapUI ever turn red?

Tags: soapui

I have inherited a soapui test suite, and even when all the test steps fail, the test case itself still remains a green tick.  Is this expected behaviour?  Or is the setup somehow wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected (and unfortunate?) behaviour.

That green check (tick?) is just an icon that SoapUI uses for "test case". The icon never changes.

You can see example in their own documentation: [SoapUI 101: Beginner’s Guide to API Testing](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-101-beginners-guide-api-testing/), if you scroll down to section "Data Driven Testing".